# show/hide div in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have date and time within two different div. I have two check box 
1. Add additional- It will add one more div of each date and time
2. Time/date will be same- It will add just date div. need to hide time div.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="addMore(keyAdd);" ng-model="keyAdd"> <label for="dateCheck">Add Additional</label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="keyOnlyDate"> <label for="configDate">Time/Place will be the same</label>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.addMore = function(Attr) {
    if (Attr && $scope.keyCount <= 2 && $scope.keyOnlyDate == false) {
        $scope.selects.push({});
        $scope.keyCount++;
        $scope.keyAdd = false;
        $scope.keyOnlyDate = false;
    } else if (Attr && $scope.keyCount <= 2 && $scope.keyOnlyDate == true) {
        $scope.selects.push({});
        $(".timePiker").hide();
        $scope.keyCount++;
        $scope.keyAdd = false;
        $scope.keyOnlyDate = false;
    }
}
```

i need to hide the timePiker based on the index value only. How to do that?

Comment: Which index value are you talking about?

Comment: Please show us your full code / jsfiddle to understand the exact problem to help you

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
ng-show ="expression"
```

or

```
 ng-hide ="expression"

 ng-if ="expression" //in this case it will be removed from Dom
```

for example

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="addMore(keyAdd);" ng-model = "keyAdd" > <label for="dateCheck" ng-if ="keyOnlyDate ">Add Additional</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use ng-class. I recommend ng-class because you are more flexible and you can create nice animation with it, for example you can transform or rotate element.

```
ng-class="{'active': expression}"
```